# stop MediaPlayer after changing the screen

Tags: java, android, multithreading, audio

I have two screens `Main.java` and `Home.java`. `Main.java` have button click for user login.

After user clicks on Login Button in `Main.java` what are things happening serially:

1. Button sound plays.
2. The credentials are matched with Microsoft SQL Server's Database
3. Launches a new Intent `Home.java`

In `Home.java` `onCreate(Bundle)`, I have created a new Thread to play sound in background:

```
// Media Player
Runnable backgroundSound = new Runnable() {
    @Override
       public void run() {
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1= MediaPlayer.create(Home.this, R.raw.welcome_message);
       mediaPlayer1.start();
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer2= MediaPlayer.create(Home.this, R.raw.welcome_tone);
       mediaPlayer2.start();
       }
};

Thread media = new Thread(backgroundSound);
media.start();
// Media Player
```

But, If I press back button this sound continue to play. Even if I exit the app this sound continue to play. What should I do so that if the screen is changed(back button, exit app, or another app, Middle Button of phone event occurs), this sound should stop.

**Knowing this is thread `media.stop` might not be good option. As `suspend()` and `stop()` both are deprecated what should I do? Interrupt this thread? Or Something else? What should stop this thread on change of screens(I discussed above)**

*NOTE: I didn't pasted too much source code(all java files). I thought it might not be necessary to feed all the unwanted content here. If it lack any details let me know I'll edit the question.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all give static media player references to your media player objects.Then implement onBackPressed() inside your activity.in that method write below provided codes.

```
if(mediaPlayer1.isPlaying())
mediaPlayer1.stop();
if(mediaPlayer2.isPlaying())
mediaPlayer2.stop();
```

Complete code will be like this

```
public class Home extends Activity {
public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1,mediaPlayer2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Media Player
Runnable backgroundSound = new Runnable() {
@Override
   public void run() {
        mediaPlayer1= MediaPlayer.create(Home.this, R.raw.welcome_message);
   mediaPlayer1.start();
        mediaPlayer2= MediaPlayer.create(Home.this, R.raw.welcome_tone);
   mediaPlayer2.start();
   }
};

Thread media = new Thread(backgroundSound);
media.start();
// Media Player 

}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
   if(mediaPlayer1.isPlaying())
mediaPlayer1.stop();
if(mediaPlayer2.isPlaying())
mediaPlayer2.stop();
   super.onBackPressed();       
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the activity lifecycle. like on pause you stop the media player.And on resume you play it back again.
You can also override the function onbackpressed inside your activity. once back is clicked, you stop the music.

> ```
>  @Override
>    public void onBackPressed() 
>    {
>        // TODO stop the music
>        super.onBackPressed();       
>    }
> ```

Comment: could you please give me a complete answer. It's just for back Button press. Also I asked should I touch the thread? or the MediaPlayer()?